# TFSConfig Accounts /ResetOwner resulting an error "Invalid column name 'DatabaseId'

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2014

I have restored `TFS` related  Databases (configuration and collections) from  a server which runs in `SQL 2012` to a  new machine in `SQL 2014`

The `TFS` version that I am trying to upgrade is from 2010 to 2013. The first step for  Remapping the databases went fine. But while setting the command

```
TFSConfig Accounts /ResetOwner   --- resulting an error "Invalid column name 'DatabaseId'  .
```

Somebody please help me on this.